# Loading SQLite dll Runtime

Tags: c#

I need to use SQLite dll in runtime. I get assembly like :

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("System.Data.SQLite");
```

Then, create object SQLiteConnection Class and add `ConnectionString` Property  to him like:

```
object sq_connection = a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection");
sq_connection.GetType().GetProperty("ConnectionString").SetValue(sq_connection, "Con...");
```

But then, I need to create `SQLiteCommand` object with `CommandText` and `ConnectionString` properties :

```
 object sq_command = a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand");
 sq_command.GetType().GetProperty("CommandText").SetValue(sq_command, sql);
 sq_command.GetType().GetProperty("Connection").SetValue(sq_command, sq_connection);
```

It's all ok with `CommandText` but on `"Connection"` property VS throw `AmbiguousMatchException`. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think you are way over-complicating this. You only need one line to have all your database calls work with SQLite: creating the database. Everything else is handled by interfaces that are known at compile time:

```
using(var sq_connection = (IDbConnection)a.CreateInstance("System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection"))
{
    sq_connection.ConnectionString = "Con...";
    using(var sq_command = sq_connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        sq_command.CommandText = sql;
        // execute
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a really great solution!
But I don't understand only one thing : 
sealed class SQLiteConnection realize only `ICloneable`, `IDisposable` interfaces Like : 
    `public sealed class SQLiteConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable, IDisposable`.
So, how this worked ?